# Multiple .apk filtering in the Google Play store serves older version of app

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I was wondering if anyone could have any information that could help us with a problem we have been having.

We have released an app as an update from an existing app. The old app is still available so we have a multiple apk scenario.

The old app has compatibility for screens described in the manifest as small, normal, large and xlarge. (there doesn't seem to be any density declaration) The api is 8+
The new app has compatibility for screens described in the manifest as

```
 <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Our api is 14+

Problem is, when the client using a Sony Experia Z1 (which seems to be a "large" screen) installs the app on the store, they get the old version of the app.

According to the documentation, the store should serve the new version because it has a higher version number (the phone being compatible with both versions, old and new) but it isn't and i can't find any extra documentation or people having any similar issues.

Is there anything you can think of that is making this happen?

I was reviewing the other things in the manifest, for example the "native platforms" but that seems to be because the original developers used some NDK and i don't think that would be the problem (?)

The other thing is the permissions which as fast as i know, any phone should be able to do and should not be the issue.

In the new app they are

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.SEND_SMS
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

in the old app they are

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.GET_TASKS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

If anyone can think of anything, we would be very thankful!

Comment: If you view the apk in the play store console switch to advance mode. Above your current apk version you should see a message like "Previously active APKs supported more devices than those in the draft configuration. Some devices will not receive upgrades.". Click more and find the details of which devices will be excluded from the new app update.

Comment: Thank you Lionel, this still doesn't explain the problem with the Sony but it did explain why small tablets also saw the old version as one of the permissions was TELEPHONY, which tablets don't have.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same signing keys for signing new APK file. Otherwise Google Play will not consider the app as upgraded version.