# Why is Play Store serving an old APK to some phones?

Tags: android, google-play

Some of my users are being served an old APK from Play Store

I've opened up advanced mode, and I can see this message

```
Previously active APKs supported more devices than those in the draft configuration. Some devices will not receive upgrades. Less
Devices currently running version 1 are no longer supported by the current configuration. Such devices will not receive upgrades. 
API levels in range 14+ and 
Release track containing any of [ALPHA] and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN] but excluding any of [android.hardware.WIFI]
```

I've checked:-

- The Details pane for each APK, and the requirements read the same
- The manifest in my source code control and there have been no changes other than the version number

How do I figure this one out?

NB. I've read [Multiple .apk filtering in the Google Play store serves older version of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176903/multiple-apk-filtering-in-the-google-play-store-serves-older-version-of-app)

Comment: have you updated the min-sdk version in manifest recently or added any hardware feature as required true?

Comment: no. As I said in the question, the **only** change to the manifest is the version number.

Comment: Also, check whether your apk size has exceeded 32 MB or so?

Answer (score 0):

First I will advise you to check min version but you saw that you already did it. So check if some of new staff in your new implementation version are using some widget and/or component that only available for a specific group of devices as fragments, spinners, hardwares resources as GPS, NFC, etc...

I little couple of things are not warning by IDE or compiler and just catch when you upload you APK on Google Play.

Even if you not using it try to down min version until IDE and/or compiler get and show you a warning or error.